# How to make screen resolution permanent ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, display-resolution, xrandr

I tried the following and it works but I want to run the shell file on system start up.

I don't have `.xprofile` file or `lightdm.conf` in the system. I tried various nvidia drivers which only breaks the system with a blank screen.

script:

```
cvt 1366 768

xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1368x768_60.00

xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode "1368x768_60.00"
```

In the above script how to dynamically add `VGA-1` to `addmode` and `newmode`

Some time when I restart the system, `VGA-1` becomes `VGA0 or VGA1` which breaks the system where I am not able to login

Comment: I never saw the behavior of VGA-1 turning into VGA0 or VGA1, but my advise is to enhance your script by running xrandr without argument, grep for VGA, put the result it into a variable and alter your addmode and output lines to use the variable.

Comment: @WillemK Well it happened when I restarted my system. Some times, VGA1 changed to VGA0

Comment: @WillemK I am new to linux. How do I add grep to argument?

Answer (score 1):

To automate your script, put the following in a script and give it x-bits (chmod +x file)

```
#!/bin/bash
Display=$(xrandr | grep VGA)
ModeSet=$(echo "$Display" | grep '1368x768')

if [[ "$ModeSet" != "" ]]
then
  echo "Mode already set:  $Display" | cut -d'(' -f1
else
  xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
  xrandr --addmode ${Display%%\ *} 1368x768_60.00
  xrandr --output  ${Display%%\ *} --mode "1368x768_60.00"
  echo -e "Mode set: \c"
  xrandr | grep VGA | cut -d'(' -f1
fi
```

Comment: actually the cvt command can be omitted, and the script should only run once as the mode should be remembered. Then again, your system may not remember it. You will have to experiment with it.